# jQuery - Loop next() on click function

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to loop the next(); function where if I click a fourth time `.active` is added back to the first instance of `resize__icon`. My current code doesn't loop and removes the `.active` class from all `.resize__icon` elements.

```js
$(".resize").click(function() {
  var xcontext = $(".resize");
  var xactive = $(".resize__icon.active", xcontext);
  var xnext = xactive.next();
  xactive.removeClass("active");
  xnext.addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.resize {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1.3rem;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.resize__icon {
  padding: 0.9rem;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.resize__icon.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="resize">
  <div class="resize__icon active"> </div>
  <div class="resize__icon"> </div>
  <div class="resize__icon"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding a check at the end of your code to see if there are no active elements.

```
// Check if an element exists with both classes
if ($(".resize__icon.active").length == 0) {

  // If not add active to the first .resize__icon
  $(".resize__icon").first().addClass("active");

}
```

DEMO:

In this example, I tweaked some of your earlier code to make it a little more condensed but this is unnecessary. The only required addition to your code is the block given above.

```js
// Add click event listener to .resize
$(".resize").click(function() {

  // Condensed original code (this is not necesary)
  var xactive = $(this).find(".resize__icon.active");
  xactive.removeClass("active");
  xactive.next().addClass("active");
  
  // Check if an element exists with both classes
  if ($(".resize__icon.active").length == 0) {

    // If not add active to the first .resize__icon
    $(".resize__icon").first().addClass("active");
  }

});
```

```css
.resize {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1.3rem;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.resize__icon {
  padding: 0.9rem;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.resize__icon.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="resize">
  <div class="resize__icon active"> </div>
  <div class="resize__icon"> </div>
  <div class="resize__icon"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try following code-

```
$(".resize .resize__icon").click(function() {
  // this will remove class form all dom elements
  $(".resize .resize__icon").removeClass("active");
   // now make clicked button active by adding class to it
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```